# Listing Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C . I want to list an array's values.

In PHP :

```
$arr = array("laguna", "megane", "clio");
foreach($arr as $no => $name)
{
     echo $no." ) ".$name;
}
/*
Output :
0) Laguna
1) Megane
2) Clio
*/
```

How can i do it in C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C

```
char* arr[] = {"laguna","megane","clio",NULL};

for( int i = 0; arr[i]; i++)
{
   printf("%d) %s\n",i,arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: I can't use `i < 3` i don'T know how many elements array have. How can i count them?

Comment: @Eray What do you mean? Your PHP code has 3 elements. Count them. If you want to know how to do dynamically sized arrays say so. Your question makes no mention on this. We can't read your mind.

Comment: There you go, just don't add elements after 0. Aka null, mind you this is in C

Comment: @Eray: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` will give you the number of elements in your array (like the one in this example above that's *not* dynamically allocated) so you don't have to count them yourself. Having a `NULL` represent the end of a sequence as Nico does is a decent alternative to having to keep track of the size when you only have a pointer and not an actual array.

Comment: @AusCBloke An array of pointers is still an array. Please rephrase for other readers.

Comment: @Nico: I wasn't talking about an array of pointers, I was talking about a pointer such as one returned by `malloc`, as opposed to a *real* array, where you can't use `sizeof` to get the size.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: The OP's question was originally tagged as C++, so I'll leave this answer as-is for those who might be curious about a C++ specific method*

You can use the `for_each` algorithm inside of `algorithm` ... it works with any object that can be dereferenced and incrementally interated (i.e., supports `operator++`).

The input arguments to the `for_each` algorithm are a pointer (or iterator) that points to the start of the array or container object if you're using STL containers like `std::vector`, etc., a pointer or iterator that points to one past the end of the object, and then a function that will be applied to each member of the array or container.

For instance:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

//pointer to the start of the array
int* start = array;

//pointer to one position past the end of the array
int* end = array + sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

//function applied to each member of the array
void function(int a)
{
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "Value[" << count++ << "]: " << a << endl;
}

//call the for_each algorithm
for_each(start, end, function);
```

Comment: I would suggest
int* end = array + sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *arr[] = {"laguna", "megane", "clio", NULL};
    char **name = arr;
    while(*name){
        int no = name - arr;
        printf("%d ) %s\n", no, *name++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are not the same language. Using C++ [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) in a recent C++ dialect, you might try (*untested* code):

```
std::vector<std::string> vecstr;
vecstr.push_back("laguna");
vecstr.push_back("megane");
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it= vecstr.begin(); 
     it != vecstr.end(); it++)
   std::out << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a good look at using arrays in c++ .

```
 // arrays example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int billy [] = {16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
int n, result=0;

int main ()
{
  for ( n=0 ; n<5 ; n++ )
  {
    result += billy[n];
  }
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

You can go one step ahead and use STL containers like set and map.
http://ideone.com/U62Q8

Answer (score 0):

In c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array[6]= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
void main() {
  int len=sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
       printf("Elements in position :%d :%d ",i,array[i]);
  }
}
```